# Create Order Number using a Stored procedure select and update within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, deadlock

I need to create a method of creating a unique order number.  Each order number must always be greater than the last, however they should not always be consecutive.  The solution must work within a web farm environment.

Currently have a stored procedure which is responsible for getting a new Order number, which has to be seeded so that the order number is not consecutive. The application is now moving from a single server to a web farm and therefore controlling access to the stored procedure via a using a lock in C# is no longer viable as a method of controlling access. I have updated the stored procedure as below however I am concerned that I am going to introduce blocks\locks\deadlocks when concurrent calls occur.

The table and index structures are as follows

MyAppSetting Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyAppSetting](
        [SettingName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [SettingValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyAppSetting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SettingName] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My Order table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyOrder](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [OrderNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyOrder_OrderNumber]  DEFAULT (N''),
        ... rest of the table
     CONSTRAINT [PK_MyOrder] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The Sql Transaction

```
    Set Transaction Isolation Level Serializable;

    Begin Transaction

        --Gen random number
        SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@HighSeed - @LowSeed -1) * RAND() + @LowSeed), 0)

        --Get Seed
        select @Seed = [SettingValue] FROM [MyAppSetting] where [SettingName] = 'OrderNumberSeed'

        --Removed concurrency and not required as order numbe should not exceed the seed number
        --select @MaxOrderNUmber = Max(OrderNumber) FROM MyOrder

        --if @MaxOrderNumber >= @Seed Begin
        --  Set @Seed = @MaxOrderNumber
        --end

        -- New Seed
        Set @OrderNumber = @Seed + @Random

        Update [MyAppSetting] Set [SettingValue] = @OrderNumber where [SettingName] = 'OrderNumberSeed'

        select @OrderNumber

    Commit
```

Comment: Are you asking if this can cause deadlocks? If so the answer depends on what else accesses those tables, but I don't think that procedure would deadlock itself. If you are asking about if there are better ways to generate the order number you would need to describe the requirement more clearly.

Comment: It seems to me this script has a concurrency issue. I think you need to lock bvc_Order BEFORE you get MAX and keep it lock until you update the bvc_WebappSetting table.

Comment: @Rattle, good point I have added my requirements

Comment: @FLICKER Yes you are right logically the max OrderNumber should never exceed the seed anyway so it’s adding complication, and probably introduce a table lock which would cause issues in the rest of the application.

Comment: The requirements for OrderNumber sound a lot like a guid.  Why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the revised SQL you provided you only select and update one table. You can do this in a single query which should avoid the risk of deadlocks, and avoids the need for an explicit transaction.

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderNumber ( NextOrderNumber int)
INSERT OrderNumber(NextOrderNumber) values (123)
```

Get Next Order Number

```
DECLARE @MinIncrement int = 5
DECLARE @MaxIncrement int = 50
DECLARE @Random int = ROUND(((@MaxIncrement - @MinIncrement -1) * RAND() + @MinIncrement), 0)
DECLARE @OrderNumber int

UPDATE OrderNumber 
SET @OrderNumber=NextOrderNumber, NextOrderNumber = NextOrderNumber + @Random 

SELECT @OrderNumber
```

I changed LowSeed and HighSeed to MinIncrement and MaxIncrement as I found the term Seed here to be confusing. I would use a table dedicated to tracking the order number to avoid locking anything else on the MyAppSetting table.

I would also challenge the requirement of having an order that always increases, but not sequentially - without this a GUID would be easier. 
Alternatives to consider would be to have the order number derived from the time somehow - with last digit to identify different servers.